# Change first value for a column for each ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL as follows:

```
+----+-------------------+----+
| ID |       Date        |    |
+----+-------------------+----+
| A  |    '2019-01-05'   |    |
| A  |    '2019-01-06'   |    |
| A  |    '2019-01-04'   |    |
| B  |    '2019-06-07'   |    |
| B  |    '2019-06-25'   |    |
| C  |    '2019-05-05'   |    |
| B  |    '2019-04-10'   |    |
+----+-------------------+----+
```

I want to add a `count` column so that for each unique ID, the count is set to 1 on the earliest date, otherwise it is 0. So the table above should look like

```
+----+-----------------+--+---------+
| ID |      Date       |  |   Count |
+----+-----------------+--+---------+
| A  |    '2019-01-05' |  |       0 |
| A  |    '2019-01-06' |  |       0 |
| A  |    '2019-01-04' |  |       1 |
| B  |    '2019-06-07' |  |       0 |
| B  |    '2019-06-25' |  |       0 |
| C  |    '2019-05-05' |  |       1 |
| B  |    '2019-04-10' |  |       1 |
+----+-----------------+--+---------+
```

I tried creating a new table with `SELECT DISTINCT ID, min(Date) FROM table;` so that I would get the earliest date for each unique ID in a row, then join the original table on that small 'lookup' table, but `SELECT DISTINCT ID, min(Date) FROM table;` only gives me one row, not three in this case.

Comment: You need `GROUP BY ID`

Comment: @Barmar OP needs UPDATE, not SELECT. Optimal solution does NOT use GROUP BY. The solution which you refer do NOT solve OP's taks.

Comment: @Akina He's creating another table that he's going to join to find the row with the minimum, that needs `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Barmar the duplicate link has nothing to do with this requirement. The OP does not want to count.

Comment: It's the same problem and solution for all aggregation functions.

Comment: @Barmar NO. 2 copies are used during UPDATE, and GROUP BY not needed.

Comment: @Barmar this question is not about aggregation.

Comment: @forpas It's about getting the minimum date for each ID, that's aggregation.

Comment: @Barmar ```UPDATE src t1 LEFT JOIN src t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.date>t2.date SET `Count`=1 WHERE t2.date IS NULL```

Comment: @Barmar right, and use that minimum date to assign a value. So it is not about counting.

Comment: @forpas Whenever you just get one row instead of multiple rows with an aggregation function, the problem is that you forgot `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
  t.Date = (select min(Date) from tablename where id = t.id) as Count
from tablename t
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by ID to get the minimum for each.

```
UPDATE table AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MIN(date) AS minDate
    FROM table
    GROUP BY ID
) AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.date = t2.minDate
SET t1.count = 1
```